# Replacing "while" statement with acceptable alternative

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm having a brainfart and cant seems to figure out how to replace this "while" for an acceptable analog that will work with the same results. Every thing I try makes the function produce inaccurate results (???) which drives me mad.

```
public void AllDecendantsList(Transform transform)
{
    List<Transform> tempList = new List<Transform>();;
    int CurrentTransformIndex = tempList.Count;
    foreach (Transform t in transform)
    {
        if (condition)
        {
            //stuff
            this.myDict.Add(t.gameObject, value);
        }
        tempList.Add(t);
    }
    while (CurrentTransformIndex < tempList.Count)
    {
        Transform currentTransform= tempList[CurrentTransformIndex++];
        if (currentTransform.childCount > 0)
        {
            foreach (Transform t2 in currentTransform)
            {
                if (condition)
                {
                    //stuff
                    this.myDict.Add(t2.gameObject, value);
                }
                tempList.Add(t2);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the purpose of `childCounter` in your program? You initialize it, you update it, you don't read it. What is the function of a variable you don't ever read?  More generally: if it's not broken then why are you trying to fix it?

Comment: Why is there a variable called returnValue which is never returned?  This code seems to be deliberately hard to understand. **Start by making your code easier to understand**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just another way to do it?  You could always perform an implicit conversion and just set an integer equal to CurrentTransformIndex.

```
int  i = CurrentTransformIndex;
for(i; i < returnValue.Count; i++)
  {
     //Do something
  }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Yeah, I tied that but for the love of god it gives me incorrect output data. I'm baffled. Original works. However, I can't use original because I'm not exactly in a vanilla/pristine einvironment and compiler/decompiler I use turns it into this mess https://pastebin.com/6yCzFqVe

Comment: It could be because you are setting CurrentTransformIndex equal to tempList.Count before the foreach loop runs( and adds an object "Transformation").  Try either setting CurrentTransformIndex equal after the foreach loop OR setting i = tempList.Count after the foreach loop.  Let me know if that works

Comment: Oh, I think it might be because I'm adding new entry to the list while iterating. Damn, why did it work in original though then?

Comment: Yeah that's what I meant by adding the object "transformation" to your list.  I'm guessing it didn't work because you were trying to use CurrentTransformIndex in the while loop here: tempList[CurrentTransformIndex++]